# Pass variable as a param of a ExO PowerShell cmdlet New-ManagementRole

Tags: powershell, exchange-online

I am trying to automate new management role creation via a PowerShell script and I am using -EnabledCmdlets to create the management role with access to only required PowerShell cmdlets.

```
New-ManagementRole -Name "Test Role" -Parent 'Distribution Groups' -EnabledCmdlets Get-DistributionGroup,New-DistributionGroup
```

Here for EnabledCmdlets, I am getting the required cmdlets from a json, stored as an array.

```
{
  "name": "Distribution Groups",
  "cmdlets": [
    "Get-DistributionGroup",
    "New-DistributionGroup"
  ]
}
```

However when I parse the json and pass the cmdlets into the command, it gives below error.

```
Write-ErrorMessage : Ex200BA5|Microsoft.Exchange.Data.DataValidationException|The management role must contain at least one cmdlet.
```

I have tried different ways as shown below, non of them worked.

```
$content = @'
{
  "name": "Distribution Groups",
  "cmdlets": [
    "Get-DistributionGroup",
    "New-DistributionGroup"
  ]
}
'@

$json = ConvertFrom-Json $content

#1
$enabledCmdlets = "'" + ($json.cmdlets -join "','") + "'"

$params = @{
  Name = "My ($($json.name))" 
  Parent = $json.name
  EnabledCmdlets = $enabledCmdlets
}

New-ManagementRole @params


#2
$enabledCmdlets = $json.cmdlets -join ","

New-ManagementRole -Name "My ($($json.name))" `
        -Parent $json.name `
        -EnabledCmdlets $enabledCmdlets


#3
$enabledCmdlets = "'" + ($json.cmdlets -join "','") + "'"

New-ManagementRole -Name "My ($($json.name))" `
        -Parent $json.name `
        -EnabledCmdlets $enabledCmdlets
```

When I execute the equivalent cmdlet manually, I am able to execute the command without any issue. How can pass cmdlet value dynamically to the script?